# Prove that there exists a function tending to zero and satisfying some conditions

Tags: functions, limits

Can we prove that for all natural numbers $n$, there exists a function $\epsilon _{n}$ satisyfing : $\forall t > -1, \sqrt[n]{1+t}=1+\frac{t.\epsilon_{n}(t)}{n}$ and $\lim_{t \to 0}\epsilon _{n}(t)=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given equation, $$ \epsilon_n = \frac{n}{t}((1+t)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1) \to  \frac{(1+t)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{1} \to 1$$

as $t \to 0$ by L'Hopital for $"\frac{0}{0}"$.

So the answer is *No*.

Answer (score 2):

But, by the binomial theorem,
for fixed n,
$(1+t)^{1/n} = 1 + t/n + (t^2/2)(1/n)(1/n-1) + ...
= 1 + t/n + O(t^2)$
so that 
$\epsilon_n = 1 - t\frac{n-1}{n} + O(t^2)
= 1 + O(t)$,
not $0$.

Your computation
$$\epsilon_n = \frac{n}{t}((1+t)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1) \to  \frac{(1+t)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{1}$$
is correct, 
but the right-hand limit is $1$
as $t \to 0$, not $0$.

Comment: Indeed, fixed it.